# Android Studio can't update public variable

Tags: java, android, variables, if-statement

I am very new to Java and Android Studio. I am creating a login script, everything works but I need to set a variable to `false` or `true`. Java tells me I can't update the variable because I am using a `public void`. So I am trying to work around that but it's not working at all. This is my code

```
public String errorNumber = "0";
```

That variable is being used in the following method

```
public boolean validate() {

        boolean valid = true;


        String email = _emailText.getText().toString().trim();
        String password = _passwordText.getText().toString().trim();

        final String Password = _passwordText.getText().toString().trim();
        final String Email = _emailText.getText().toString().trim();

        if (email.isEmpty() || !android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) {
            _emailText.setError("Vul een geldige email in");
            valid = false;


        } else {
            _emailText.setError(null);
        }

        if (password.isEmpty() || password.length() < 8 || password.length() > 20) {
            _passwordText.setError("Vul een geldig wachtwoord in");
             valid = false;


        } else {


            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, REGISTER_URL,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {

                            String[] output = response.split(":");
                            String output2 = output[2];
                            String[] setNumber = output[1].split(",");
                            String responseDetails1 = output2.replace("\"", "");
                            String responseDetails = responseDetails1.replace("}", "");
                            String responsNumber = setNumber[0];

                            Log.d("RESPONSE1", response);
                            Log.d("RESPONSE2", setNumber[0]);
                            Log.d("RESPONSE3", responseDetails);

                            if(responsNumber.equals("0")){

                                 errorNumber = "0";

                                //Toast.makeText(login.this, responseDetails, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                Log.d("THERE IS AN ERROR", responseDetails);
                            }else{

                                _passwordText.setError(null);

                                 errorNumber = "1";

                                //Toast.makeText(login.this,  responseDetails, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                Log.d("LOGIN SUCCESS", responseDetails);

                                //Intent i = new Intent(login.this, login.class);

                               // startActivity(i);
                            }


                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Toast.makeText(login.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }){
                @Override
                protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                    Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
                    params.put(KEY_PASSWORD, Password);
                    params.put(KEY_USEREMAIL, Email);

                    return params;
                }

            };

            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

        }
        Log.d("ERRORNUMBER", errorNumber);

        if (errorNumber.equals("0")){
            valid = false;
        }

        Log.v("VALID STATUS", ""+ valid);

        return valid;
    }
```

Sorry for the long block of code, but it basically updates `valid` to true or false. Because I can't do this from within my `if` statements I needed to work around it, so I thought why not setup a variable and later check if that is set to 1 or 0? Then update the valid boolean accordingly.

Nothing I have tried so far works and I am out of solutions. I have searched the web but I can't find anything that explains me why I can't update that update variable so I can use it in my last `if` statement.

Comment: Where's the public variable you mention in the title?

Comment: it is here, sorry it say private because i also tried that but it was set to public. Still  doesn't work. 

public String errorNumber = "0";

Comment: Your question says you can't update a public variable, but the one you showed in your code is private.

Comment: that was a mistake, i was trying everything, just didn't see it was still private as it should public.

Comment: now it says public

Comment: You are changing the value from a listener. That listener is executed when some condition changes which is *after* method `validate` finishes. Therefore any code in `validate` won't see the change because it didn't happen yet.

Comment: that seems not correct as validate() is being invoke when the user taps a button to login. The whole code in validate() works except for the part when the errorNumber needs to be updated. Even the log.d work. But the errorNumber resised out site of the method as a public var and it needs to be updated when validate() runs then at the end it should be checked in an if statement which value it holds. I do normally swift 2 which makes things like this easy.

Comment: Why in the world are you using a string to store a number?

Comment: as i said before i tried everything int string even made de boolean public. Nothing works. I would rather get some help instead of questions why i use a string and not an int. It is because i am trying everything and nothing seems to work for me.

Comment: You don't change the value anywhere in `validate`. `validate` just initiates a HTTP request. That is done in the background and the response is received (and therefore `onResponse` runs and changes `errorNumber`) only _after_ `validate` ends.

Comment: Btw. you should see from the logs that `ERRORNUMBER` and `VALID STATUS` is printed _before_ `RESPONSE1` or `LOGIN SUCCESS`.

Comment: that true, only thinking about it now you say it. So how should i go about this so that it works properly.I have no idea how to do this. Should bring it to the foreground? No idea where i should go from here.

Comment: You can't do networking in the UI thread (btw. I don't think you could in iOS either).

Do whatever you need to do in `onResponse` instead.

Comment: well you can't because it would execute after you try to do everything, you do it after you got the respons and loaded the array or json array. I will try that. Java is pretty hard compared to php or swift :). Only been doing it for 3 days.

Comment: i am looking at the code and i can't figure out how make this sync so that rest of the code goes when the http request is completed. there should be a way right, can some one point me to sample so i can understand this part.

Comment: You can't do it synchronously (well, you can but it's damned complicated). Java programming is event-based, not synchronous at all. Typically, you just have some listener that you call when you know the answer.

Comment: so i have to create a listener who catches something so i can execute the rest of the code after the http request. sounds like a really hard thing.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, what you are doing wrong is that you are declaring variables IN the method. This results in them being deleted once you reach the end of the method. There are multiple ways to solve this, I will give you two ways.

1. You should declare 'valid', 'email' and 'password' variables outside of every method, at the beginning of the class. That way, when you invoke the method, whatever you did with variables is saved.
2. You could make the validate() method return a variable. For example, have the method return 'valid' variable and then you will get the value of 'valid' once you exit the method.

EDIT: just thought about 3. way you could do this. You could make a separate class, make an object out of it in your validate() method and return the whole object. That way you can get all 3 variables without declaring them for the whole class.

```
Public class email () {
    Boolean valid;
    String password;
    String email:
}
```

If this answer is not understandable, ask for further clarification. I can also post example code if needed.